# migrate from vite version 4 to vite version 5 - import sprite from 'assets/sprite.svg';

Tags: reactjs, github, svg, import, vite

Help me migrate from vite version 4 to vite version 5
The main problem is that when I upgrade vite to version 5.0.10, `import sprite from 'assets/sprite.svg';` stops working. Locally, everything works correctly, but when deployed to gitHub, the path is written incorrectly. When installing `vite 4.4.5`, everything works as it should!

`import sprite from 'assets/sprite.svg'` is located in `src/components/Header/Header.tsx`

I will be very grateful for your help. The link to the repository is https://github.com/Illia-Shatokhin/react_vite_ts

I read all the documentation, tried 1000 variants, but could not fix it